# Quicker way to reverse strings in list

Tags: reverse, processing-efficiency, python-3.7

I have about more than 40,000 strings in a list, and I want to reverse these and then compare with the original list.

I used a for loop to create the reverse list:

```
for word in list:
  reverse_list.append(word[::-1])
```

Yet, this is taking a lot of time!
Is there a more efficient way, or is waiting something expected? I want to improve efficiency.

Comment: You can forgo the reversal and actually do the logic while you are going through the list once.

Comment: @trilogy could you provide an example?

Comment: you can implement this logic with one pass. Don't complicate the thing. Make use of negative index in python or find the index with eg; `List[max_index - current_index - 1] <= List[current_index]; current_index+=1`

Comment: @song0089, HaridasN 's answer ^^^

Answer (score 0):

If the array is dynamic and has things coming in and out of it, when appending to it you could also append its reversed self into a separate array. Otherwise if this is a one-off computation then its efficiency should't be of much concern.